# Как вытащить регулярным выражением?

Tags: c#

Как вытащить регулярным выражением Имя ?

```
<span class="userName" itemprop="name">Имя</span>!
```

Пытался так:

```
String Rate = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Response, @"itemprop=""name"">(*)</span>").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: А где ваш код, которым вы уже пытались что-то вытащить?

Comment: А для данной конкретной строки вот вам: `/>([^<]+)</`.

Comment: Для разбора HTML используйте парсер HTML. Регулярки — неправильный путь.